# Anonymous user in Django

Tags: django, authentication

How can I just enable anonymous user in Django? 
I mean, what is the minimum I should do to be logged in as anonymous first time I go to my site?

Regards, Arshavski Alexander.

Comment: [anonymous user authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authorization-for-anonymous-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the auth middleware is in place then you're the anonymous user whenever you're not logged in.

Comment: It's in place. But I want to see "Logged as anonymous in the top right corner when I go to admin page and I don't see it.

Comment: That would be a limitation of the admin page and not the auth subsystem.